# SQLite queries to search the contents of 3 columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to execute a query in sqlite (Android) which looks like

> select * from Table where name1 = "name" or name2 = "name" or name3 = "name"

My code is:

```
String where = SYMPTOM1 + "= \"" + symp1 + "\" " + "or " 
                     + SYMPTOM2 + " = \" " + symp1 + " \" " + "or " + SYMPTOM3 + " = \" "
                + symp1 + " \" ";

cursor = mDb.query(false, TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
```

This code retrieves the value where name1=name... the or part isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting extra spaces to name2 and name3 values like this:

```
"\" " + symp1 + " \""
```

Notice the space between `symp1` and the closing quote.

To fix it and a number of other issues, consider using `?` placeholder and bind arguments instead, e.g.

```
String where = SYMPTOM1 + "= ? or " 
                 + SYMPTOM2 + " = ? or " + SYMPTOM3 + " = ?";
String whereArgs[] = new String[] { symp1, symp1, symp1 };
cursor = mDb.query(false, TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, where, whereArgs, null,
            null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @laalto.  what is the syntax in this case.
    String x = SYMPTOM1 + "= \"" + symp1 + "\" " + "or " + SYMPTOM2
    + " = \" " + symp1 + " \" " + "or " + SYMPTOM3 + " = \" "
    + symp1 + " \" ";

  String y = SYMPTOM1 + "= \"" + symp2 + "\" " + "or " + SYMPTOM2
    + " = \" " + symp2 + " \" " + "or " + SYMPTOM3 + " = \" "
    + symp2 + " \" ";

  String where = "(" + "( " + x + ")" + "and" + "(" + y + ")" + ")";

  Cursor cursor = mDb.query(false, TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, where, null,
    null, null, null, null);